# how to align the text vertically in center in a fixed height?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an image of `height=79px` and `width=138px` and I want to align the text vertically center through `<li>`. For this, I write my css as :

```
#left-container .col1 li
{
    background:url(../images/button.png) no-repeat top center;
    height:79px;
    line-height:79px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.5625em; /* 25px */
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    position:relative;  
}
```

This is okay with single word, e.g. `Qty.`, but not with 2 words, e.g. `Item Options`, `Hold Selected`,  etc.

So, can you please suggest whether I should create separate classes for each button to adjust line heights separately, or is there any other unified way to adjust all the line heights in just one class?

Comment: You should probably set line-height to 79 **px** and not just a number. as a number, it multiplies by the font-size, which will yield a gargantuan line-height.

Comment: sorry, it my mistake, but i set my line height to 79px. not 79, sorry its my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the line-height property to 79px, each line of text will be 79px height.

To vertical center a text inside an element, you have to use the vertical-align property, together with the display:table property for the container element. The idea is to make the element work like a table.

So you need a container element acting like a table, an inner element acting like a table-row, and inside that, elements acting like table cells.

I managed to let your .col1 acting like a table:

```
#left-container .col1 {
    display:table;
}
```

Then your ul acting like table rows:

```
#left-container .col1 ul {
    display:table-row;

}
```

And then each li item acting like a table cell, adding this CSS to yours:

```
#left-container .col1 li  {  
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

I removed the line-height property.

Note that you need now to have multiple ul for each row you want to have in the "table", so if you want to have the same structure as before, you need to have something like this:

```
<div id="left-container">
    <div class="col1">
        <ul>
            <li>List item 1 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 2 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 3 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 4 </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>List item 5 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### **UPDATE**

Look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/W2H6a/22/

Comment: Very very thanks for your great idea, but if I hover the <li>, I also need an rollover image that will be in gloosy blue look. So, how that can be done, as per your coding where you used display:table-cell; instead of display:block;

Comment: Do you need it as an <img> tag or a background-image property of the <li>s?

Comment: Anyway a hover effect can still be applied to the display:table-cell <li>, and you can specify both width and height of the <li>, as you would do for a display:block element. Try this:

#left-container .col1 li:hover {
    background:red;
}

Comment: +1 for going into center aligned text, I'd always managed to figure out an image, but massive line-height always stopped me from trying to center-align text. Cheers Jose.

Comment: thanks a lot dear.. now it is finished...I am a Web Designer and thanks for your great support for today.. May I know more about yourself ?

Comment: Oh I'm really happy to be able to help! :)
Please select my answer as appropriate if you think it is, so I can be more useful to the community with more points.
You can check my website in my profile page, I'm a webmaster and JS programmer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling with this problem for a long time. Tried your solution and it worked just like that.. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="left-container">
    <div class="col1">
        <ul>
        <li>List item 1 </li>
        <li>List item 2 </li>
        <li>List item 3 </li>
        <li>List item 4 </li>
        <li>List item 5 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#left-container .col1 li  { 
    height:79px; 
    width:138px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-weight:bold;   
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    margin-bottom:1px;   
    border: 1px solid green;  /* Just to check */
 }
```

See the demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/W2H6a/3/

Comment: aren't `<li>`s supposed to be in `<ul>` or an `<ol>` tags ?